# How do I update a SharedResources.resx file in DotNetNuke 7

Tags: dotnetnuke, resx

I am trying to edit a SharedResources.resx file for the ViewProfile control in DNN 7.

The file path is \DesktopModules\Admin\ViewProfile\App_LocalResources\SharedResources.resx. The default profile view has an 'Avatar' image which we are not implementing and I would like to remove the [PROFILE:PHOTO] token and surrounding image tag.

I am able to do this manually, but the page never seems to update with my changes.

So I go into the Language Editor and do the update there. However, when I click Save a new file is created called SharedResources.Portal-0.resx and my changes are saved to that file and are still not applied to the site.

The other resource files (type filename.ascx.resx) do not display this behavior. If I update a value it is reflected upon page refresh on the site.

I would like to know why this is happening and what the correct method of updating files of this type is.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you positive that the string is coming from that shared resources file, and not somewhere else?

Comment: I took the image alt text "Profile Avatar" that I saw on the profile page and did a search through the entire Dnn file system for all occurrences. It occurs additionally in the *.template files and in User.ascx.resx. I decided to do it via the Admin > Languages > Edit method instead and that is what I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the SharedResources.resx file manually, instead of through the language editor, and see if that change takes effect.

The thing to keep in mind in doing that though, is that the file will be overwritten the next time you do an upgrade of DNN, so you would need to modify that file again.

By changing that file however, you can at least see if the change takes effect, if it does not, than would have to believe the info is somehow coming from a different location.